# In ancient Sumer, what would happen if a child inherited an estate?

Tags: ancient-history, sumer, inheritance

Let us suppose that in ancient Sumer, a wealthy man who is the head of his household has two living children, a daughter and a son.  The daughter is older, but both offspring are considered to be young children, too young to be married.  The man's wife and mother of his children is deceased, and the man has no concubines, only employees.  The man has a female cousin who is married to the head of her household.  That is the full extent of this man's known living relatives.  The man also has many friends in his city.

Now let us suppose that this wealthy man dies.  My research on the inheritance customs of ancient Sumer leads me to believe that the man's son should inherit the estate and become head of his household.

My question is: **What (if any) procedural allowances to the process of inheritance would have been made for the fact that the deceased man's son and presumed heir is a small child?**

In other words, would some adult person act as parent and conservator of the estate until the son became old enough to act as head of the household, would the child be expected to muddle through things he was not old enough to understand on his own, or would some other person inherit the estate?  If some adult was to take charge of the estate on behalf of the child, who might that be - the man's cousin or her husband, an employee, a family friend or some other person?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main sources for law of this region would be the laws of Hammurabi. The relevant code would appear to be #29, which allows a [guardianship](https://books.google.com/books?id=lRUMEAAAQBAJ&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&lpg=PT14&dq=hammurabi%20inheritance%20minor%20children&pg=PT14#v=onepage&q=hammurabi%20inheritance%20minor%20children&f=true) to be established, at the cost of a third of the sons inheritance:

> The Hammurabi Code provided guardianship and care for minor children
> after the death of their father. For example, law 29 stated that if a
> son was too young to conduct his fathers business, the judges would
> give one-third of the fields and garden to his mother, and she would
> raise him to adulthood.

You provide a special case, in which case the same judges mentioned above would have to determine who would then be best appointed as the guardian.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful.  I saw this law, but couldn't find anything that mentioned what would happen if the mother was also deceased.  I'll wait a day or two before accepting this, just in case something better is posted, though.

Comment: That's a nice find, but those paragraphs in the Code of Hammurabi (§27–§41 in the conventional numbering) apply specifically to the case of a "soldier" (*rēdûm*) or a "fisherman" (*bā'irum*) with a (military) service obligation (*ilkum*) to the king and a house, field and/or orchard entrusted to him by the king in return for this obligation. I'm not sure how far these rather specific laws can be generalized, but at least they do provide _one_ example of how inheritance in such a situation _could_ work. I might try to provide a more comprehensive answer later, if I can find any sources.